# Error Domain Handling in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, validation, core-data, error-handling

I have the following code from a Swift 1.2 tutorial, which I can't manage to convert to Swift 2:

```
var val: AnyObject? = self.value
var error: NSError?
if !self.myManangedObject.validateValue(&val, forKey: self.key, error: &error) {
    var message: String!
    if error?.domain == "NSCocoaErrorDomain" {
        var userInfo:NSDictionary? = error?.userInfo
        var errorKey = userInfo?.valueForKey("NSValidationErrorKey") as String
        var reason = error?.localizedFailureReason
        message = NSLocalizedString("Validation error on \(errorKey)\rFailure Reason:\(reason)", comment: "Validation error on \(errorKey)\rFailure Reason: \(reason)")
    } else {
        message = error?.localizedDescription
    }
    // Create some alerts with the message
}
```

The `self.value` in the first line refers to the value for a CoreData attribute.

I understand I need to change the code to a `do { try } catch { }` construct. I am guessing line 3 would look something like this:

```
try self.myManagedObject.validateValue(&val, forKey: self.key)
```

However, this doesn't work as Xcode first suggests removing the pointer, and then says

> "Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type
>   'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer (...)"

Also, I am not sure how to handle the `error?.domain` statements. From searching the internet, the examples I found suggest handling the error types in an enumeration, but I don't see how that would apply here.

Btw, would it be possible to use the current version of Xcode to update this code from Swift 1.2 to 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the minimal working example for what you are trying to do:

```
var mgc : NSManagedObjectContext!
var any : AnyObject?

do {
    let valid = try mgc.validateValue(&any, forKey: "myKey")
    // branch based on the valid
} catch let error as NSError {
    // here you go with your error handling
}
```

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, that is actually exactly what I managed to achieve myself. The problem is that `&any` won't compile, like I wrote in the question. In the catch-block I'm assuming I could check for the error domain the same way like in the old code.
Edit: I'm an idiot, I was using let instead of var, that's why the pointer wouldn't compile.

Comment: @MaxiMus try cleaning the build and rebuilding - I had problems with the compliation as well. But this IS the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, found the mistake. About my last question. If I wanted to have Xcode (try and) update Swift 1.2 code for me, would the only way to do this be to install a 6.x version of Xcode, make a project there with the 1.2 code and then open this with a 7.x version?

Comment: @MaxiMus I do not think so - the error handling changed too much to be easily and automatically convertible. I think these types of changes have to be performed by the programmer himself, not via automatic xcode conversion

Comment: Yes I understand that. It's just a technical question though, even if I would get a 'wrong' conversion, I would like to see what Xcode suggests.

Comment: @MaxiMus okay, i do not know for sure what xcode would do - but there is nothing preventing you from trying it out, right?

Comment: "If I wanted to have Xcode (try and) update Swift 1.2 code for me, would the only way to do this be to install a 6.x version of Xcode" is not something I can "try out" ;) But thanks anyway.